# How to declare 'id' in Kivy widgets added by a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, for-loop, kivy, widget

On MacOs i have this Python3 script:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
class app(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('lab.kv')
app().run()
```

and this Kivy file('lab.kv'):

```
#: import TextInput kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput
BoxLayout:
    on_parent:for i in range(7):self.add_widget(TextInput(id=???,text=str(i)))
```

My question is: can I declare dynamic IDs for each widget?
For example:

```
id='my_id'+str(i)
```